# Netbeans PHPUnit Selenium with proxy

Tags: netbeans, selenium, phpunit

### Problem

I'm trying using PHPUnit with Selenium in Netbeans and having problems running my tests using a proxy which requires a username and password.

I created a new firefox profile and installed a plugin called AutoAuth that saves the username and password for the proxy.

I specify this custom firefox profile when starting the Selenium Server so when I running my tests from the command line, it does not prompt me for a username or password.

### Environment

When running the tests through Netbeans, Firefox prompts me for the username and password for the proxy. 
If I check the firefox extensions for the browser instance Netbeans has launched it does not have AutoAuth installed.

AutoAuth is installed on the default and on the custom profile i created, so I'm not sure where the profile for this instance of Firefox launched by Netbeans is stored.

### Fixes I have tried

Specifying the manual proxy in Netbeans with username and password but this does not even launch the browser, it only works when i set it to no proxy

Specifying the browser in Netbeans options using the argument -p  but this had no effect.

Making the test sleep while I install AutoAuth for the instance of Firefox Netbeans launches, this installs sbut when I re-run the test the extension has not saved.

This is driving me nuts has anyone got phpunit working with a proxy in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the Firefox Profile in the code? If not please try to